# Fundraiser website, with real-time donation counter

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript

For a fundraiser website, I'm trying to implement a feature on the page that shades in a image which is currently black and white to colour. The image needs to fill in colour (from left to right) based on the percentage of donations received (via paypal and other methods). Once the percentage of donations is complete the image will be completely in colour.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way I could make this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code so far and tell us what exactly you have problems with.

Comment: AJAX request to get the percentage. Something like [ProgressBar.js](http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning bec, thank you for your question. Since you are asking for ideas (and have not posted any code), I will post an answer which I hope points you in the right direction.

*As a preface to my answer:*

- You don't mention how or when you are calculating the percentage of donations received, so I'm assuming the data will be available when you draw/update your image.
- You don't mention if you want your image to be implemented in a progress bar or other kind of slider (where the image is "skinned" over the control and changes color as the control works), or if you will just display the image by itself on the page.

A *very* simple idea could be the following:

1. Place color and grayscale copies of the same image side by side on the webpage.
2. Use the percentage of donations to determine the visible area of those images. For example: if you are at 33 percent of the goal for donations, you can display the first third of the color image, and then display the remaining two-thirds of the grayscale image. (You may need to put this in something more dynamic - not just in the site view or form section - if you need donations to be tracked in real time. Maybe AJAX to the rescue?)

Based on some initial searching online, people have probably implemented ideas like this using CSS, javascript, and jquery (among other languages). Here are some links that talk about similar issues (hopefully you can extract knowledge from their code to benefit your project):

[JQuery / HTML / CSS Grayscale to color image slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076442/jquery-html-css-grayscale-to-color-image-slider)
*(Another stackoverflow question)*

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover
*(HTML5 code to convert grayscale images to color when hovering over them)*

Hope this helps. I know the links do not provide exact answers to the question, but some of what they cover could be used to create your project.

Comment: Thanks, for the help :). The image will be displayed by itself on the page. I'll try to get my head around it all and let you know how it goes